# Jquery Modal Window proceeds download request

Tags: jquery, redirect, window, modal-dialog

Hopefully this will be basic but if I create a Jquery click connected to a link that is supposed to download a document. However, before the download is initiated, I want the user to complete a quick profile form.

Suppose a I use a `<a href="ProfileFormToBeCompleted.html" class="modal">` in the html page and the following Jquery function.

```
//SCRIPT TO APPEND 
$('a.modal').click(function() {
    $('#modal_content').html('<p id="modal_image_wrapper"><img src="' + $the_link
        + '"class="modal_placeholder" /></p>');
    showModal();
});
```

I can get the modal window to display and submit the form but how can I redirect the user to the download once the validation is finished?

Comment: I just don't know what you're asking. Are you wondering how to make an HTTP request for the document with jQuery?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I have a <a> tag in the HTML file that is bound to a JQuery function that opens a modal window for the user to fill out. Once the form is submitted and validates, how can I redirect the user? I can make the form disappear once it validates but I would prefer to redirect them (business rule decision, not mine) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is a redirect in javascript, you can do this:

```
window.location = '/path/to/page';
```